# Discord.js giveaway command timer and member selection

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

how would i make a giveaway command for my bot where the embed shows the time left (updating ever 2 mins) and when the giveaway is over, it selects a random user that has reacted to the message.

```js
const { getMember, formatDate } = require("../../functions.js");
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");
const { owner } = require("../../config.json");

module.exports = {
    name: "create",
    aliases: [],
    category: "giveaway",
    description: "Creates a Giveaway",
    usage: "< ITEM | TIME >",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        let channel = client.channels.get("660171456444891189");

        if (!args[0] || !args[1]) return;
        let reward = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        let time = args[0]

        let giveawayEmbed = new RichEmbed()
            .setColor(0x0099ff)
            .setTitle(`**__${reward.toUpperCase()}__**`)
            .setDescription(`Hosted By: <@${message.author.id}>`)
            .setFooter("React to join the giveaway")
            .setTimestamp()
            .addField("Time left:", `${time}`)

        channel.send(giveawayEmbed).then(msg => {
            msg.react("")
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1 way to do it, its check event `messagereaction add`, because in **discord 11.x.x** you can get users who react the message. So you need greate some database, place message id here,users array,timestamp of event and somethink else. Then check event msgreaction add , and add users id to data base. And then with set inverval check when.

This is the message reaction event.

```
 client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
      let message = reaction.message, emoji = reaction.emoji;

      if (emoji.name == '✅') {
              // We don't have the member, but only the user...
              // do sumethink
              });
      }



  // Remove the user's reaction
  reaction.remove(user);
});
```